# Getting values from void * array

Tags: c, winapi, pointers

I am making use of an API (DynamoRIO) that intercepts function calls. The wrap_find_first_file_pre method is called before the function is executed and the wrap_find_first_file_post is called after the function is executed. The method signatures are provided by the API. In the pre method one can obtain the parameters of the function, however they cannot be obtained in the post method. The API specifies that if you need to make use of the parameters in the post method, you have to pass them through the OUT void **user_data parameter.

I am passing two values as a void ** OUT parameter and accessing them from a second function through a void * parameter.  I am getting a casting error and I am not sure that I am accessing the values in the correct manner in the second function.

```
static void wrap_find_first_file_pre(void *wrapcxt, OUT void **user_data){
    *(user_data) = (void *)find_path; //LPCTSTR 
    *(user_data + 1) = (void *)ffd; //WIN32_FIND_DATA
}

static void wrap_find_first_file_post(void *wrapcxt, void *user_data){
    LPCTSTR find_path = (LPCTSTR) user_data[0];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd = (WIN32_FIND_DATA) user_data[1];
}
```

Comment: `user_data` is not dereferencable, and that is what `user_data[0]` etc is doing. And I'm not too keen on your first function's cast of to `(void*)` of what appears to be a *struct*; not a pointer.

Comment: Is your `void* user_data` parameter the base address of the array of `void*` that you passed in to your first function? If so, this is doable (but egads is it f'ugly). I'll burn an answer if that is what is actually happening.

Comment: error(1): 'void *' : unknown size error(2): cast of 'void' term to 'non-void'

Comment: OP: the information you added should go in the main body of your post so that future users can understand it. This is a community site that aims at creating a body of knowledge, not just a place where you get *your* problems fixed.

Comment: Noted.  Never was my intention to make my question inaccessible by future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty standard pattern to allow you to pass data around where the API doesn't have any idea what sort of data you might want to pass. The `void **user_data` is **not** an array of `void *`, it's just an *out* parameter for a `void *`. You can only return a single `void *` with it.

What you should do is something along these lines:

```
struct my_user_data {
  LPCTSTR find_path;
  WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
};

static void wrap_find_first_file_pre(void *wrapcxt, OUT void **user_data) {
  my_user_data *ud = malloc(sizeof(struct my_user_data));

  ud->find_path = /* However you get this */;
  ud->ffd = /* However you get this */;

  *user_data = ud;
}

static void wrap_find_first_file_post(void *wrapcxt, void *user_data) {
  my_user_data *ud = (my_user_data *)user_data;

  /* Do something with ud->find_path and ud->ffd */

  free(ud);
}
```

Please ignore any typos etc., of course, as I have no way of providing you tested code.